# PHP: Uso de password_hash en sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, encriptación

¿Hay alguna incompatibilidad entre `password_hash()` y las sentencias preparadas en PHP?

Estoy intentando diseñar un sistema de registro de usuarios para una página web y utilizando `sha1()`, por ejemplo, no da problemas, pero al usar `password_hash()` falla; el código es el siguiente:

```
$sql = "INSERT usuarios VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)";

$sentencia = mysqli_stmt_init($conexion);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($sentencia, $sql);

$hash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); #$contrasena procede de $_POST

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sentencia, "sss", $nombre, $correo, $hash); #$nombre y $correo también

if(mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia) == 1)
{
    $mensaje = "Usuario registrado con éxito";

    return $mensaje;
}
else
{
    $mensaje = "Se ha producido un error durante el registro";

    return $mensaje;
}
```

Si sustituyo `$hash` por `sha1($contrasena)` al vincular la consulta y las variables el usuario queda registrado en mi BD.

La estructura de la tabla la podéis ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la definición de la estructura de la tabla `usuarios`?

Comment: Qué versión de PHP tienes?

Comment: @Marcos Hecho. Ahora que lo veo, ¿será un problema de la longitud del campo?

Comment: @IndiraRivas Estaba usando la 7.2.18 pero acabo de cambiar a la más reciente que permite WAMP, la 7.3.5.

Comment: @Marcos En efecto, le he metido un VARCHAR 300 y ahora funciona.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO:

Cambié la longitud del atributo contrasena de mi BD de VARCHAR 50 a 300.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

*PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Usar el algoritmo bcrypt (predeterminado a partir de PHP 5.5.0). Observe que esta constante está diseñada para cambiar siempre que se añada un algoritmo nuevo y más fuerte a PHP. Por esta razón, la longitud del resultado de usar este identificador puede cambiar con el tiempo. **Por lo tanto, se recomienda almacenar el resultado en una columna de una base de datos que pueda ampliarse a más de 60 caracteres** (255 caracteres sería una buena elección).*